# Disabled jquery on a div to fix conflicting issues with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js

I'm working on a Drupal project that imports JQuery on all its pages. We started to use Vue.js by injecting it directly in the HTML pages for the development of dynamic components (not for a SPA).

The problem is that we have JQuery UI that conflicts with Vue.js. It will directly modify all the inputs of Vue.js by readapting their styles.

Is it possible to disable JQuery UI on a particular div, which would contain Vue.js? Without having to disable it on the whole page, because our header has a burger menu that uses JQuery UI.

Comment: You could apply more specificity to a default style applied to your Vue part (with some dirty `!important`) for it not to be overridden by jQuery UI. Or scope jQuery's styling somehow. Lot of possible CSS solutions here IMO.

Comment: The problem is not only CSS, Jquery also adds span and div to clone a select. I would really like to find a way to completely disable it.

Comment: What is it targeting exactly? You could maybe change the HTML tag to avoid it being selected.

Comment: The project is so huge and they added JQuery years ago as a CDN, we don't have the hand on this and they don't want to change this... But well I found a way, not the best one but it works. I used this to destroy and rollback all my selects to the origin =>        $('select').selectmenu("destroy")

Answer (score 0):

We found a fix to correct this conflict between Vue.js and JQuery. This method will not completely disable JQuery on a given scope, but will disable a behavior that we were having trouble with.

$('select').selectmenu("destroy")

More about the method destroy here:
https://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-destroy